# Adding variable to text string and adding new line in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code

```
$scriptpath = "C:\Test"
$scriptname = "mount.bat"
$myimage = Read-Host 'Enter the file name of your image'
if (Test-Path $scriptpath\$scriptname) {
 Remove-Item $scriptpath\$scriptname
}
Add-Content $scriptpath\$scriptname ':Loop 'n "C:\Program  
Files\file.exe" -f \\host\"Shared Folders"\$myimage -m V: `n if not 
%errorlevel% equal 0 goto :Loop'
```

I can't get powershell to output the variable correctly in the output batch file it just says "$myimage" and not the file name. I have tried using the break ` ' symbols but no luck. I also cannot get powershell to export onto a separate line. If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using (a) variable references (`$myimage`) and (b) escape sequences such as `` `n `` (to represent a newline) in your string, you must use *double* quotes to get the expected result.

(*Single*-quoted strings treat their contents *literally* - no interpolation takes place.<sup>[1]</sup>)

Furthermore, since your string has *embedded* double quotes, they must be escaped as `` `" ``

Here's a fixed version; note that I've used *actual* line breaks for readability (rather than `` `n `` escape sequences in a single-line string):

```
$myImage = 'test.png'
":Loop
`"C:\ProgramFiles\file.exe`" -f \\host\`"Shared Folders`"\$myimage -m V:
if not %errorlevel% equal 0 goto :Loop"
```

---

<sup>[1] The only interpretation that takes place is to recognize escape sequence `''` as an embedded `'`.</sup>